# Как на php отправить http-запрос?

Tags: php, запрос

```
POST /v2/posting/fbo/get HTTP/1.1
Host: api.api.ru
Client-Id: 836
Api-Key: 0296d4f2-70a1-4c09-b507-90005567b9
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "posting_number": "1305-0001-1"
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как будет выглядеть код для отправки этого запроса?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.api.ru/v2/posting/fbo/get",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('posting_number' => '1305-0001-1'),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Client-Id: 836",
    "Host: api.api.ru",
    "Api-Key: 0296d4f2-70a1-4c09-b507-90005567b9",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Думаю будет вот так выглядеть запрос

Answer (score 1):

Пример POST-запроса с использованием потоков (на вариант использованием CURL-библиотеки вам уже дали ответ):

```
<?php
$content = <<< EOT
{
    "posting_number": "1305-0001-1"
}
EOT;
$opts = [
    'http' => [
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header'  =>
            "Client-Id: 836\r\n" .
            "Api-Key: 0296d4f2-70a1-4c09-b507-90005567b9\r\n" .
            "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'content' => $content
    ]
];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$response =  file_get_contents("http://api.api.ru/v2/posting/fbo/get", false, $context);
if ($response === false) {
    // обработка ошибки
} else {
    echo $response; // успех!
}
```

А лучше, вместо того, чтобы хардкодить:), воспользоваться готовой http-client библиотекой. Одна из таких - [guzzlehttp/guzzle](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle)